# What is known of convergence and divergence of the following series?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let the serie $\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k (z-i)^k$ converge for $z = 4$ and diverge for $z=-8$. What is known of convergence and divergence of the following series?

**(a)** $\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k (1+i)^k$

**(b)** $\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k 9^k$

**(c)** $\sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k a_k 5^k$

A good criterion I could use here would be the radius of convergence (respectively, radius of "divergence").To do this, I thought to use the following theorem, but I'm not sure whether it is the right solution.

**Theorem (Cauchy):** Given a power serie with complexe coefficients $a_k$, $$\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k z^k,$$ let $$R= \frac{1}{\lim \sup_k |a_k|^{1/k}}$$ ($0 \leq R \leq \infty$). Then the serie converge absolutely in the ball $B(0,r)$, uniformly over the entire ball $\bar{B}(0,r)$, such that $r<R$, and it diverge if $|z|>R$

A part of the answer say we have convergence inside $B(i,\sqrt{17})$ and diverge outside $B(i,\sqrt{65})$. We don't have information between both ball.

Is anyone could explain to me how to obtain this radius of convergence?

Comment: You should rather using the (simpler looking facts) that if a series $\sum a_nx^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, then $\sum a_nx^n$ converges for every $x$ such that $|x|<R$ and $\sum a_nx^n$ diverges for every $x$ such that $|x|>R$, thus if $\sum a_nx^n$ converges then $|x|\leqslant R$ and if $\sum a_nx^n$ diverges then $|x|\geqslant R$. Thus, the hypothesis that $\sum a_n(4-i)^n$ converges and that $\sum a_n(-8-i)^n$ diverges tell you that $R$ is such that... hence...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tried to solve with your hint, but I am not able to obtain the balls $B(i \sqrt{17})$ and $B(i \sqrt{65})$. Could you be a bit more precise?

Comment: Sure. Which information on $R$ did you get from my first comment?

Comment: For (a) $|1+i|=√2<√17$ which implies that $z=1+2i$ lies inside the circle of convergence.

Comment: @Did I am probably needed of a radius of convergence equal to $R-i$. The problem is I don't know how to obtain the particular R.

Comment: What? The radius of convergence is a nonnegative real number (or $+\infty$), *certainly not a complex number*. What does $R-i$ have to do here? Once again: which information on $R$ the radius of convergence of the series $\sum a_nx^n$ do you have?

Comment: We have $|4-i|= \sqrt{17}$, $|-8-i|= \sqrt{65}$, $|1+i|=√2<√17$, $9 \geq \sqrt{65}$ and $\sqrt{17} \leq 5 \leq \sqrt{65}$. Is it good on this way?

Comment: Yes--although you still did not answer the precise question I now asked twice.

Answer (score 0):

The radius of convergence  $r$ is at least $\sqrt {17}$ and at most $\sqrt {65}.$ We  have convergence in (a) because $|1+i|=\sqrt 2<\sqrt {17}< r$ and divergence in (b) because $|9|=9>\sqrt {65}>r$. We do not have sufficient information to decide (c).